# How to separate action creators into a separate file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to put my action creator into a separate file.  I get the error

> Error dispatch is not defined.

// AddNewNote.js

```js
// AddNewNote class is here

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actionNoteCreate: actionNoteCreate,
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddNewNote);
```

//noteActions.js

```js
import actionTypes from '../constants/actionTypes';

export const actionNoteCreate = (text) => {
  dispatch({
    type: actionTypes.NOTE_CREATE,
    payload: text,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dispatch should be inside your `mapDispatchToProps` and removed from your actionCreator:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actionNoteCreate: text => dispatch(actionNoteCreate(text)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddNewNote);
```

However, the best way to do that is probably to simply use an object in mapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    actionNoteCreate
};
```

react-redux will automatically wrap it with dispatch.

"[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props."
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md